# Simplifying $\frac1{gt}\sqrt{g/2h}\,dx$ in free fall equations

Tags: calculus, physics

The relevant equation: $x(t) = \frac12 gt^2$ , $dx/dt = gt$ , $T=\sqrt{2h/g}$

$dt/T = (dx/gt)\sqrt{g/2h} = 1/(2\sqrt{hx}) dx $

I do not see how $(dx/gt)\sqrt{g/2h}$ turns into $1/(2\sqrt{hx}) dx $

Can someone please show me how this was simplified?

Comment: What is $dt/T$?

Comment: @user7530 Looks like $\frac{1}{T}\,dt$, with $dt$ being a differential. $T$ is the total time of falling from height $h$.

Comment: $dt/T$ is the probability density.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a matter of solving for $t = \sqrt{2x/g}$ and then plug and chug:
$$\frac{dx\sqrt{g}}{gt\sqrt{2h}} = \frac{dx\sqrt{g}}{g\sqrt{2x/g}\sqrt{2h}} = \frac{dx}{2\sqrt{xh}}.$$

Comment: How did I not see something so simple! But thank you, you are life saver. I was busting my head for the past 2 hours now. :)